# Proof check of the fact that Compactness in Metric Spaces implies Closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

In apostol's analysis, this theorem is given a different proof(i feel so), but i wonder if this works as well(which is in fact the technique used to prove this theorem for the Euclidean Space $\mathbb R^n$)

Theorem : Suppose $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $S \subset M$ is a compact set. Then $S$ must be closed.

Proof : Suppose for the sake of contradiction, $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ which is not in $S$.

We construct a covering of $S$ as follows - define $r_k=\frac{|x-x_k|}{2}$ for all $x_k \in S$.

Then the balls $B_S(x_k,r_k)$ cover $S$, and thus by compactness, there is a $m$ such that $S\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}B_S(x_k,r_k)$.

Choose $\text{min}\{r_k\}_{m\geq k\geq 1}=r_{\text{min}}$.

Fix a $x_k$ in $S$ and choose an element $y$ in the ball $B_M(x_k,r_{\min})$ (possibly different from $x_k$)

Thus, $d(x_k,x)\leq d(x_k,y)+d(y,x)$ so that $d(y,x) \geq 2r_{k}-d(x_k,y)>2r_{\min}-r_{\min}=r_{\min}$ so that the ball $B_S(x,r_{\min})$ does not contain $y$, and varying $x_k$ all over $S$, we find that this contradicts our assumption that $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

This proof is just a general thing of the proof which appears before for this theorem where $M=\mathbb R^n$ and the metric is our well known Euclidean norm.

I would like to know if this proof is valid (which i doubt as then Apostol would've included this) and if wrong where is the fault.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write the proof as follows: let $x$ be an accumulation point of $S$ which is not in $S$. For each $s \in S$ we define $r(s) = \frac{d(s,x)}{2} > 0$ (the absolute value only works in $\Bbb R$ and its subspaces, this works in any metric space). Then $$\{B(s, r(s)): s \in S\}$$ is an open cover of $S$ and so by compactness of $S$ has a finite subcover $$B(s_1, r(s_1)), \ldots B(s_n, r(s_n))$$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$.

(Your notation suggests that $S$ is countable as you use indices $s_k$ right away, while I only index the finitely one we use in the finite subcover. The cover we start with is as big as $S$ is, so possibly uncountable.)

Now let $$r_0 = \min\{r(s_i): i = 1, \ldots, n\}$$ which is the minimum of *finitely* many numbers that are $>0$ so $r_0 > 0$. Now as $x$ is a an accumulation point of $S$ we can find $y \in B(x,r_0)$ such that $y \in S$.

Let $s_i$ be one of the centres from the finite subcover such that $y \in B(s_i, r(s_i))$ (it exists as we have a (sub)cover of $S$):

$$d(x,s_i) \le d(x,y) + d(y, s_i) < r_0 + r(s_i) \le 2r(s_i) = d(s_i,x)$$

which is a contradiction (a real number cannot have $r < r$).

Comment: Very nicely written. +1 To put it differently if $S$ is compact and $x\notin S$ then there is a some fixed real $r_0>0$ such that $d(x, s) \geq r_0$ for all $s\in S$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes, that’s another, more positive, way of putting the last part.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct.

The finitely many open balls $B(x_k,r_k)$ cover $S$, but for the same centers, the finitely many open balls $B(x_k,r_{min})$ are not guaranteed to cover $S$.

If you vary the choice of finitely many covering balls, then $r_{min}$ is no longer fixed, but you need a fixed $r_{min}$ to get the desired contradiction.

Comment: I see. Any way to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am extremly sorry. Perhaps i got distracted. So basically its $d(x,x_k)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,x_k)$ so that $d(y,x_k)\geq d(x,x_k)-d(x,y)>2r_k-r_k=r_k$ which implies the contradiction.

Comment: In your above comment, you have $d(x,x_k)-d(x,y) > 2r_k-r_k$, but you don't know that $d(x,y) < r_k$, so the inequality $d(x,x_k)-d(x,y) > 2r_k-r_k$ is not justified.

Comment: Your proof attempt is along the same lines as Apostol's proof, but Apostol's proof is correct, and no more complicated than your attempt. If you have questions about Apostol's proof, perhaps post a new question.

Comment: we do right? We choose $y$ to be in the ball $B_S(x,r_{\min})$ so thay $d(x,y)<r_{\min}<r_k$ by the way we defined $r_{\min}$

Comment: You chose $y$ in the ball $B(x_k,r_{min})$, so that gives you $d(x_k,y) < r_{min}$.$\;$It doesn't give you $d(x,y) < r_{min}$.

Comment: Yesh, that was for the (wrong) proof i provided in my question, and i forgot to mention later. :) thanks!